# Any existing methods to find a drop in a noisy time series?

Tags: python, time-series, signal-processing

I have a time series (array of values) and I would like to find the starting points where a long drop in values begins (at least X consecutive values going down). For example:

Having a list of values

```
[1,2,3,4,3,4,5,4,3,4,5,4,3,2,1,2,3,2,3,4,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

I would like to find a drop of at least 5 consecutive values. So in this case I would find the segment **5,4,3,2,1**.

However, in a real scenario, there is noise in the data, so the actual drop includes a lot of little ups and downs.

I could write an algorithm for this. But I was wondering whether there is an existing library or standard signal processing method for this type of analysis.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this pretty easily with pandas (which I know you have). Convert your list to a series, and then perform a `groupby` + `count` to find consecutively declining values:

```
v = pd.Series([...])
v[v.groupby(v.diff().gt(0).cumsum()).transform('size').ge(5)]

10    5
11    4
12    3
13    2
14    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit how this works? I just have basic experience with pandas. Does this account for the fact that there might be a small increase in the middle of an decline?

Comment: @swbandit Small increase in the middle of an increase? Basically, all I'm doing is finding consecutive groups of increasing values, and the grouping on each set of values, and eliminating those groups which are smaller than 5.

Comment: Sorry, meant a small increase in the middle of a decline. Which means you could have 5,4,3,2,3,2,1

Comment: @swbandit Unfortunately, this method cannot. It is not so trivial to account for that either.

Comment: @swbandit if you have other follow up questions, would appreciate if you could accept the answer and open a new post. Thanks.

Comment: You answer is helpful but it does not address the problem fully. So I can't accept it as an answer.

Comment: @swbandit I cannot approve of question askers who do not specify their complete problem and then expect answerers to mind read them and write a complete answer even though no mention of it is made in the OP. I'm telling you, one more time, to either open a new question, or struggle with your problem yourself. Your "actual problem" that you so casually asked as a follow-up cannot be solved as a trivial extension to code that solves your "current problem" as mentioned in your question.

Comment: @COLDSPEED My original post included the detail that you have omitted. My follow up was to remind you that you didn't address the full question. Also, you are assuming that just because you don't have a better answer, I should accept the one you've given. I would like to remind you that Stackoverflow is about good answers and not just about points. I'm not accepting your answer just to get an up vote on my question. I'm not point-hungry like you.

Comment: @swbandit StackOverflow is also about good questions, which your question is not. If the "little detail" that I missed was so important, maybe it should not have been so little? And yes, I answer questions for points, so what's _your_ point? My motivations for answering your questions are irrelevant here.

Comment: @COLDSPEED If you think the question is bad, you should tell me how to improve it. You missed the detail. You are making it seem like a small detail.